# How to pass data from one page to another page using angular fragments?

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular7-router

I'm trying to send data another page while navigating to another page.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/homePage', { fragment:"hello world"});
```

I'm not sure how to receive my fragment inside my homepage.
what i have tried his below here in my homepage.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.fragment.subscribe((fragment: any) => {
      console.log("My hash fragment is here => ", fragment)
    })
}
```

> I'm getting undefined i'm not sure how to receive the fragment any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to print the console.log in my home page by changing the below

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/homePage', { fragment:"hello world"});
```

to this

```
this.router.navigate(['parameter-to-device'], { fragment:"hello world"});
```